# Rendering html in backbone not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have an issue with the following code: the div `reward_view` is not being populated. Render function is being run but `this.el` seems to be undefined, why?

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({  
    el: '#reward_view',
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log(this)
        console.log(this.el)
        $(this.el).html('<h1>Hello' + '</h1>');
        return this; // for chainable calls, like .render().el
    }
});

var myItem = new Item();

myItem.fetch();
var reward_view = new ListView({model:myItem});
reward_view.render();
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="reward_view" class="bs-callout bs-callout-info">

        </div>
```

Comment: Well i have tried your code and ther is no problem with the render function. I have deleted the model(Item) and in the view i am not passing any model like 'new ListView()'. Well it is printing "Hello". Check what value you are getting after fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/dguK9/). I suspect you are doing all this before your document is ready, so `#reward_view` is not yet to be found.